# Why csv.reader is not pythonic?

Tags: python, csv

I started to use the [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) in Python 2.6 but you can't use `len` on it, or slice it, etc. What's the reason behind this? It certainly feels very limiting.

Or is this just an abandoned module in later versions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't use len or slice because it is an iterator. Try this instead.

```
import csv
r = csv.reader(...)
lines = [line for line in r]
print len(lines) #number of lines
for odd in lines[1::2]: print odd # print odd lines
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was an iterator. I thought it was a multi dimensional list.

Comment: You can replace lines = [line for line in r] with lines = list(r)

Comment: You can use `itertools.islice` if you need to slice an iterator.